# How to delete download cache?

Tags: php, html, http-headers, download

When I launch second time the application trying to make a new download then it is the previously downloaded content data which is downloaded ! Here is code :

```
$output = RP_MAIN . 'docbook/data/myfile.pdf';          
header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.'manuel.pdf'.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
ob_clean();
readfile($output);
```

So how to clear the download cache before downloading ?

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl+F5` will force a browser refresh and clear the cache.
However to make the page load without using the cache each time, you can try this -

`$output = RP_MAIN . 'docbook/data/myfile.pdf?'.rand();`

This generates a random number on the end of the file name each time the page is loaded, so the browser will think it is a new file each time and not use the information stored in the cache.

Comment: this technique of adding a parameter does not work !

Answer (score 0):

Add a random parameter onto the file URL so your browser thinks its a new file:

```
$output = RP_MAIN . 'docbook/data/myfile.pdf?version=1.5';
```

Comment: Should I change the value of the `version` param each time I want to download ?

Comment: try header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.'manuel.pdf?version=1.5'.'"');

Answer (score 0):

I add ?nocache to the end of CSV file URLs. It doesn't have to be that word specifically, but it works for opening files in Excel. It does NOT seem necessary to have a random number there, at least for Excel.